# LLVM IRBuilder: set insert point after a particular instruction

Tags: llvm

The LLVM `IRBuilder` class member function `SetInsertPoint (Instruction *I)` specifies that created instructions should be inserted before the specified instruction.

How can the insert point be set after a particular instruction? I can't find a function that can do it directly.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The insert point can't be set to be after a given instruction -- instead, you should set it to be before the next instruction.

To get a pointer to the next instruction, you can use the [`getNextNode()`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1ilist__node.html#a6ac308903849239f2f308aa180dda61b) method which is available on `Instruction`:

```
Builder.SetInsertPoint(I->getNextNode());
```

or you could turn the instruction pointer into an iterator and advance it:

```
BasicBlock::iterator it(I);
it++;
Builder.SetInsertPoint(it);
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. Any reason why we should set it before the next instruction and not after it?

Comment: @Prateek Just a guess -- conceptually. if the insert point is before an instruction, then you can insert a bunch of instructions in sequence and the insert point doesn't need to change. If the insert point were after an instruction, then unless you advance the insert point between every insert, each new instruction you insert would be before the last one (immediately after the original the insert point). So you'd be inserting instructions in reverse.

Comment: That makes so much sense. Took a couple of minutes thinking even after reading your comment. I think I understand now. Thanks @Ismail

Comment: @IsmailBadawi I guess another point is to disallow insertions after terminator.

Comment: How about when the instruction is the last one of the block or the whole program? What getNextNode() would return?